# Tool to support aptitude updates

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Running `apt-get update` can be somewhat painful at times, with error messages like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ys/emojione-picker/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

The correct way to deal with these is paste into Google, inevitably land on StackExchange's Ask Ubuntu, then spend several minutes grepping for the offending content and deciding what to do with it. Is there any tool to help with this procedure, command line or GUI based?